# How to print the content of the generator?

Tags: python, generator

```
N = [1, 2, 3]
print(n for n in N)
```

Results:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000108E780>
```

Why didn't it print?:

```
1
2
3
```

However the code:

```
sum(n for n in N)
```

Will sum up all the number in N.

Could you please tell me why sum() worked but print() failed?

Comment: You are creating a generator object and are printing the representation of that object. So that output is in fact expected. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The `print` function takes multiple arguments, and separates each argument with the string specified by the `sep` keyword argument. You could use `print(*(n for n in N), sep='\n')` to produce the expected output (or more simply, `print(*N, sep='\n')`).

Comment: Don't confuse the generator *argument* with a Perl-like structure `print(n) for n in N` (which isn't, of course, valid Python).

Comment: but the code: sum(n for n in N]) works. Could you please tell me what are the differences?

Comment: `print` function calls `__str__` method of all arguments you pass. `sum` iterates over argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because you passed a generator to a function and that's what `__repr__` method of this generator returns. If you want to print what it would generate, you can use:

```
print(*N, sep='\n') # * will unpack the generator
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, N)))
```

Note that once you retrieve the generator's output to print it, the generator is *exhausted* - trying to iterate over it again will produce no items.

Comment: `[print(n) for n in N]` syntax error in python shell

Answer (score 2):

You are literally printing a generator object representation

If you want on one line, try printing a list

```
print([n for n in N])
```

Which is just `print(N)`

If you want a line separated string, print that

```
print("\n".join(map(str, N)))
```

Or write a regular loop and don't micro optimize the lines of code

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to cast it as a list, you can try:

```
print(*(n for n in N))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Answer (score -1):

### Generator …

```
def  genfun():
    yield ‘A’
    yield ‘B’
    yield ‘C’
g=genfun()
print(next(g))= it will print 0th index .
print(next(g))= it will print 1st index.
print(next(g))= it will print 2nd index.
print(next(g))= it will print 3rd index But here in this case it will give Error as 3rd element is not there 
So , prevent from this error we will use for loop as below .
 for  i in g :
    print(i)
```