# Avoiding Side Effects in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

What is the most Pythonic and efficient way of processing a list of dictionaries and avoiding side effects (what are side effects)?

More specifically: Why does the following code produce a generator object, while just about any other similar code produces the desired output?

```
print(sum(dictionary[site] for site in dictionary) for dictionary in listofdictionaries)
```

**Some background**

I started by fiddling with `**kwargs` and produced what I would consider pretty awful code.

```
def testing(**kwargs):
    mysum = 0
    for kw in kwargs:
        mysum += kwargs[kw]
    print(mysum)


listofdictionaries = [{"site1": 1, "room1": 2, "day1": 3}, {"site2": 4, "room2": 5, "day2": 6}]

for dictionary in listofdictionaries:
    testing(**dictionary)
```

I reviewed the [Data Structures Document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) including List Comprehension and found a better way to achieve the same output:

```
listofdictionaries = [{"site1": 1, "room1": 2, "day1": 3}, {"site2": 4, "room2": 5, "day2": 6}]
for dictionary in listofdictionaries:
    mysum = 0
    for value in dictionary:
        mysum += dictionary[value]
    print(mysum)
```

And then got a little clever and shortened it a bit more:

```
for dictionary in listofdictionaries:
    print(sum(dictionary[value] for value in dictionary))
```

I really have no interest in making this a one-liner for the sake of making it a one-liner, but after reading countless list comprehension posts on Stack Overflow talking about avoiding "side effects", I feel like there may be an additional step to take this. Perhaps I'm not understanding what side effects are.

Regardless, each of these should result in the output:

```
6
15
```

Comment: There are no side effects in your code. Side effect is like mutating a data structure, assigning to a variable, printing to standard out, or writing to a file.

Comment: So, for example, your for-loop uses side-effects, `mysum += dictionary[value]` modifies the `mysum` variable. But that's fine, python is an imperative language that works that way by design. List comprehensions and it's cousins are *functional* programming constructs designed to express mapping/filtering operations, which is why they should be free of side effevts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific question only prints the representation of your actual generator object formed by the generator expression, namely this one-

```
(sum(dictionary[site] for site in dictionary) for dictionary in listofdictionaries)
```

See this answer on printing generators for further details-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616115

For this example you may be better off using a list comprehension, e.g.

```
print([sum(dictionary.values()) for dictionary in listofdictionaries])
```

You coudl print the generator by unpakcing it first but for this example it appears less readable and less effective-

```
print(*(sum(dictionary.values()) for dictionary in listofdictionaries))
```

Side effects can be quite a broad term- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) but as per the previous answer you're not modifying your dictionary in any way with these methods so there are no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close by adding a function to calculate the sum of one dictionary, and use a list comprehension like this:

```
def dict_sum(dictionary):
    mysum = 0
    for value in dictionary:
        mysum += dictionary[value]
    return mysum

print([dict_sum(dictionary) for dictionary in listofdictionaries])
>> [6, 15]
```

But, your two-liner shouldn't have any side-effects. I don't know what posts you are referring to, but if you aren't modifying the lists then you should be fine and they should be unchanged at the end.